# Can I improve a supervised learning model if I have the breakdown of the target variable?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

I have a variable `y_total`, which I aim to predict using features `x`. Actually `y_total` is the summation of different terms, so `y_total= sum(y_i)`.  I have a working model that predicts `y_total` with feature set `x` ignoring the `y_i` terms. Can I improve my model getting use of `y_i` s as the target variable while training the model? For example, would training different models to predict each `y_i` and then summing the predictions work?

Obviously I can not train a model using `y_i` s as features because they are the target variable and unknown. The feature set (`x`) is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a [`RegressorChain()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.RegressorChain.html) to predict $\hat{y}_1,... ,\hat{y}_n$ and compare the results to a model where you predict $\hat{y}_{total}$.

[`RegressorChain()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.RegressorChain.html) may help to pick up useful information regarding the $y_1,...,y_n$ in the modeling process:

> Each model makes a prediction in the order specified by the chain
> using all of the available features provided to the model plus the
> predictions of models that are earlier in the chain.

You could also compare the sum of $\hat{y}_1,... ,\hat{y}_n$ to $\hat{y}_{total}$ and see if you can gain knowledge about the quality of prediction of a single observation ex-post.

Finally you could average or stack the chained model(s) with the model predicting only $\hat{y}_{total}$.